# Webdriver-manager update throwing error

Tags: selenium

I get the following error when I try the webdriver-manager update.

```
C:\>webdriver-manager update
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied:openssl\ssl\s
23_clnt.c:769:

    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:801:14)
```

I saw some others having the same issue but throwing different errors

Comment: Facing the same problem.any update or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl

This may solve the isue

Comment: Hi - please elaborate why this is going to solve the issue. One liners are really not helpful in answers

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind firewall or if ssl token is enabled on your machine, that may cause this issue

To overcome that issue and to install protractor successfully, use webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl

I faced same problem when i tried to install protractor when i used this command, I completely bypasses ssl token verification